# find different data with sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have an Table that looks like

```
╔══════╦══════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════════════════╗
║ Key1 ║ Key2 ║ Data1 ║ Data2 ║ Data3 ║ DataNotImportant4 ║
╠══════╬══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════════════════╣
║ Foo  ║ Bar  ║     1 ║     2 ║     a ║                 4 ║
║ Foo  ║ Bar  ║     1 ║     2 ║     a ║                 5 ║
║ Foo  ║ Bar  ║     1 ║     2 ║     b ║                 4 ║
║ Foo  ║ Test ║     1 ║     2 ║     f ║                 4 ║
╚══════╩══════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════════════════╝
```

Now I would select the combinations of Key1 and Key2 where Data1 Data2 Data3 differs,
so here I would get Foo Bar as result because Data3 is not the same in alle rows.
How can I archieve this without an cursor?
Database is SQL Server 2008

Currently I use a cursor.
I select all key combinations with a group by and iterate through the list and make a group by select on my fields with the keys I get from my cursor.
The problem is when there are too many rows its getting real slow.
So I search for a set based solution.

Comment: @Sebastian You need to show your initial effort on what you have done so far. By the way, how did you generate this table?

Comment: I use this little tool http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html
I edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `group by` expression and rely on the fact that, if there are different values in one column, that must imply that the minimal value and the maximal value in that column are different:

```
declare @t table (key1 varchar(5),key2 varchar(5),Data1 int,Data2 int,Data3 int)
insert into @t (key1,key2,Data1,Data2,Data3) values
('Foo','Bar',1,2,3),
('Foo','Bar',1,2,3),
('Foo','Bar',1,2,4),
('Foo','Test',1,2,3)

select key1,key2 from @t
group by key1,key2
having
    MIN(data1)!=MAX(data1) or
    MIN(data2)!=MAX(data2) or
    MIN(data3)!=MAX(data3)
```

Result:

```
key1  key2
----- -----
Foo   Bar
```

Comment: thanks for the answer I forget that the data fields are not always numeric, sorry

Comment: @Sebastian - doesn't matter - provided [`MIN()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179916.aspx) and `MAX()` work on those data types, it will still be true. "MIN can be used with numeric, char, varchar, uniqueidentifier, or datetime columns, but not with bit columns."

Comment: The (slower) alternative is `COUNT(DISTINCT data1) > 1 OR ...`.

Comment: what should I do with bit fields?

Comment: `MIN(CONVERT(int,bitcolumn)) ...`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Group By` on multiple columns.

```
SELECT Key1=Min(f.key1), 
       Key2=Min(f.key2), 
       f.data1, 
       f.data2, 
       f.data3, 
       DataNotImportant4=Min(datanotimportant4) 
FROM   foo f 
GROUP  BY f.data1, 
          f.data2, 
          f.data3 
HAVING Count(*) > 1
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/648f8/1/0)

Comment: Isn't that grouping things the wrong way around? If the 4th row had a value of `ABC`, your query would return `Foo,Abc` instead of `Foo,Bar`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I'm not sure. What _value_ should be `ABC` in the 4th row? I have understood it in this way: get an arbitrary single row of a group of duplicate rows according to columns `data1+data2+data3`.

Comment: "where Data1 Data2 Data3 differs" implied to me that they aren't the `group by` columns.